# Cracking base64 encryption

Tags: base64, decoding

My hosting company has encrypted some data that I want decode, but it is not decoding although I know that it's base64.

Here is the code:

```
IXAik4hgXrhA4wkpeRAWW3lTc+NAWYWs4s0UCfyQ+7q7VXRwXJU6tr629ZdrFqJX
```

Comment: Why would you ask for someone to decode base64 for you? If you already know that it is base64, why don't you just decode it?

Answer (score 3):

Base64 isn't an encryption. It's a coding. There is no key in Base64. There are lots of ways to get base64 decoded (a random search shows [this](https://www.base64decode.org/) as one of them).

Your problem seems to be that the data, in addition to being coded, is also encrypted. Unless you know what it is encrypted with, there is not much chance anyone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Base64 is only the representation of data, an encoding. **Not** an encryption.

Most encryption algorithms work on bytes, which are not exactly representable in textual form. Thus, encrypted data is often encoded in base64 for transportation via textual means (like emails).

Your provider has to tell you the encryption algorithm and key. From the length of the base64 representation, it could be pretty much anything.

Yet, as the other answer correctly said, you have no chance anyone can crack this for you here; without a key and the encryption method you will not get hold of the data.